# Why opening a file in c++ with input,output,append mode gives error?

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    /* Open a file and read it*/

    ofstream file_obj;

    file_obj.open("file1.txt",ios::in| ios::out | ios::app);

    if( file_obj.is_open() )
    {
       printf("\n File opened successfully ");
    }
    else
    {
       printf("\n Error occured in opening the file");
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

It gives output

Error occured in opening the file.

But when i remove the ios:in its working fine.

Why this combination is not possible?

Comment: No, it's not a valid combination (even for `fstream`). A file can be open for reading XOR for append, not both. Just open a `fstream`  (because `ofstream` is for output only) for `in` and `out ` and move to end of file.

Comment: @Cyber But for me ios:in and ios:out worked fine.

Comment: What is the reason for the failure?  (Hint: try checking `errno`.)  Your code works for me, both with VC++ and g++ (and despite the comments of others, it is perfectly legal).

Comment: @Adriano It seems that ofstream allows both ios:in and ios:out . How this possible

Comment: @VinothKumar Why shouldn't it be possible?  The open is just passed to the `std::filebuf`, which doesn't have input and output versions.  (Of course, the only way to actually read from the file would be to obtain the `filebuf`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Its not printing the any error no. Am using g++

Comment: @VinothKumar You have to print `errno`; it doesn't print automatically.  Set `errno = 0;` before calling open, then if the open doesn't succeed, output the results using `std::cout << strerror( errno ) << '\n';`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Ya I just used perror("error"); Its not showing any error Also errno is updated as 0

Comment: @VinothKumar Strange.  Your exact code works on my machine, with both g++ and VC++, so I can assume that the request is correct, and that the open is failing at the system level, either because the file isn't there, or you are missing some rights.  But in such cases, I would expect `errno` to be set, saying why.

Answer (score 0):

The `ofstream` class is for output (writing to files) only - hence the 'o'. Use `fstream` instead - this allows both input and output.

Comment: `ios::in` and `ios::app` isn't a valid combination even for `fstream` (in C++ 98, it's allowed in C++ 11).

Comment: @Adriano Hmm I tried to compile his code and it worked fine. Maybe he put file1.txt in the Debug folder instead of his project folder.

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah There's nothing wrong with his code.  But until he posts what the error actually is, we can't say much.